# F# type 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b

Tags: f#

I want, as an exercise, to write an F# program having the type `'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b`. I am fairly new to F# but I know that -> is right associative. I came up with the following:

```
let fun1 x = x
let fun2 x fun1 = x
let fun3 x y z = x
```

and I get this from Visual Studio

```
val fun1 : x:'a -> 'a
val fun2 : x:'a -> fun1:'b -> 'a
val fun3 : x:'a -> y:'b -> z:'c -> 'a
```

Is this correct (or what I am looking for)?
Any input is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you see if any of these types match the type you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is why I asked here. I think I am ok up until fun2, but fun3 doesn't look like it. I am elaborating more on the comment below.

Answer (score 2):

If we write out what you've done as explicit signatures and functions you've done this.

```
let fun1 : 'a -> 'a =
    fun x -> x
let fun2 : 'a -> 'b -> 'a = 
    fun x fun1 -> x
let fun3 : 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'a = 
    fun x y z -> x
```

I think with fun2 you've got confused, because the "fun1" in "fun x fun1" is just the name of the 2nd parameter, it has nothing to do with the "fun1" in "let fun1 : 'a -> 'a"

if we write it like this it may become clearer.

```
let fun1 : 'a -> 'a =
    fun a -> a
let fun2 : 'a -> 'b -> 'a = 
    fun a b -> a
let fun3 : 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'a = 
    fun a b c -> a
```

if you want to write a function with signature

```
   let answer : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b =
      fun a a2b -> ??????
```

a2b is the name of the parameter with type ('a -> 'b), ie its a function that takes something of type 'a and returns something of type 'b. 
You need to fill in the gap.

If your head is hurting, get rid of all the parametric polymorphism and write a function that has signature

```
let simplerProblem : int -> (int -> string) -> string
```

and imagine calling it like this...

```
let x = simplerProblem 1 (fun i -> i.ToString())
```

and you want the answer "1"

Comment: Thanks for the input! I see what you mean by the example, but it is a bit confusing for me to find a function with type 'a->'b

Comment: that why I suggested thinking in terms of "int -> string" (or whatever)

Comment: you don't need to find an "'a -> 'b"...in fact none exist in general. If your the client code, and you an integer and a function that maps integers to strings, then you pass the parameters to the your function you're trying to create and it will create you a string.

Comment: if you didnt have this function, how would you do it?